# How to Use Color Change or DropDown Change in a formula - EXCEL

Tags: excel, colors, excel-formula, dropdown

I am preparing my Simple Salary Expense Sheet. I write down my all incomes in one column say(A) and Expenses in other column(B) then added a formula SUM(A1:A5) - SUM(B1:B10) in a cell to know my Balance amount as and when.

Now I introduce one column "PAID?" in C  and use (Yes, No) as drop down. I want to change the formula like If I change dropdown from No to Yes in C1 then the value B1 should be included for deduction from my Balance else it should not be included.

How do I do it? Seems it is simple but I cant do it and cant find it elsewhere. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following formula:

```
=SUM(A2:A6)-SUMIF(C2:C10,"Yes",B2:B10)
```

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Mrig . its working. I didn't know about **SUMIF** function. And What if I change a color in a cell. Like instead of using Yes No dropdow , if I  fill the color GREEN on the expense I paid it should include in deduction else if its RED it should not include . How can I specify colors in the formula?

Comment: @ramvijay - You can only reference the interior color of a cell via VBA, so it might not be possible using formula.

Comment: This solution is enough. I am just doing it for my own salary expense calculation. **Thanks a lot**.